# In which Deadpool comic does he kill over liking Star Wars prequels?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, deadpool

I read somewhere that Deadpool once killed a man just because he said the Star Wars prequels are better than original series.

I know he's really insane but did he really kill a man over this?

When did this happen?

Comment: And I don't blame him.

Comment: @Gallifreyan If you're deciRand, and Rand hasn't seen Star Wars, how have you seen Star Wars?

Comment: That's one of the saner things Deadpool has done.

Comment: "Somewhere" - Do you possibly mean 9gag? I saw that too :P

Comment: This must be a use of the word "insane" with which I was not heretofore familiar.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of this scene:

[image]

It comes from "Deadpool, Merc With A Mouth #5"

[image]

In Deadpool's defense, the guy was a member of AIM, generally considered a terrorist organization of evil scientists and engineers.  It wasn't like he was a random innocent guy off the street.  And, I mean, fine, he's evil... but if he can't have morals, and can't have some self-respect as a scientist... he could at least have good taste.  Liking the Star Wars prequels is really strike three.

Comment: Is it just me, or do Deadpool's lines all sound like they're being read by Ryan Reynolds in your head now too?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Agreed that the last paragraph really sold this. Basically, it is saying that he wasn't killed **just** for liking the prequels. That was meerlely the final straw.

Comment: This makes me like Deadpool SO MUCH MORE!

Comment: `Hayden Christensen is an amazing actor` said no-one ever

Comment: @Paul Yes. That is the default Deadpool voice in my head now.

Comment: For me it's half Ryan Reynolds and half Marvel vs Capcom 3 Deadpool voice

Comment: @Machavity, well no-one living, now.

Comment: Well, I actually liked the prequels better than the orgininal. I mean, just visually speaking the original series are... And then there's the sequel, which is obviously worse than any before.

Comment: @NathanCoustenoble-Just a heads-up, you do realize that saying that won't get you killed by Deadpool, right? You can still dream, though.